# Стилистика

Tags: значение-слова

"Быть на Дону - слышал о «Тихом Доне» (роман);  в цехе  - в цеху, 
в отпуске - в отпуску, на крюке - на крюку, в спирте - в спирту". Наличие таких форм с чем связано?

Answer (score 2):

Современный предложный падеж включает в себя окончания двух падежей: основное окончание Е объектного, или изъяснительного падежа, и вариантное окончание У/Ю местного, или обстоятельственного, падежа.

Выбор окончания делается по следующим правилам:

1) Окончание У/Ю употребляется  при ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВЕННОМ значении: гулять в лесу, в саду, а окончание  Е – при ОБЪЕКТНОМ значении существительного: говорить о лесе, о саде.

2) Окончание У/Ю употребляется в РАЗГОВОРНОМ стиле, а Е – в КНИЖНОМ стиле: на бале (нейтр.) и на балу (разг.)

3) Только окончание У/Ю имеют вещественные существительные со значением ПОЛНОТЫ ОХВАТА: в поту, в снегу, на клею, на меду.

4) Только окончание У пишется В НАРЕЧНЫХ ВЫРАЖЕНИЯХ: на лету, на скаку, на бегу, на весу.

5) Только одна из форм употребляется В УСТОЙЧИВЫХ ВЫРАЖЕНИЯХ: быть в долгу, быть на слуху, яблони в цвету (окончание У), но: во цвете лет (окончание Е).

6) В ГЕОГРАФИЧЕСКИХ НАЗВАНИЯХ обычно употребляется окончание Е, окончание У является исключением:  в Ростове, в Красноярске (основное окончание Е), но: в Крыму, в Клину, на Дону (окончание У как исключение).

7)  Если географические названия встречаются в НАЗВАНИЯХ ЛИТЕРАТУРНЫХ ПРОИЗВЕДЕНИЙ, то в них употребляется  окончание Е: в «Вишневом саде» Чехова, в «Восемнадцатом годе» Толстого.

Comment: Только "на бале" последние 40 лет отмечается как устаревшее, а не нейтральное. :) Судя по статистике, устарело оно более, чем на 100 лет.

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке для ряда коротких (часто односложных) существительных мужского рода, кончающихся на согласный, существует вторая форма предложного падежа — **местный падеж**. Это ударное окончание **у**: ***на балу, на берегу, в лесу, на шкафу, в порту, во рту, на полу, в бору, на виду, на ветру, на боку, во лбу, на мосту, на свету***... Всего их более ста. Форма используется исключительно с предлогами **в**, **на** в пространственном (и временном) значении. Лингвисты не вполне удовлетворены таким объяснением, так как оно *не совсем* точное ("в ярком свете" — а вовсе не "свету"), но раз мы носители языка, то просто можем использовать как привыкли, ориентируясь на привычность слуху.

Есть также очень небольшое число существительных женского рода с местным падежом. Окончание у них **-и**, и оно тоже всегда ударное: *в крови, в степи, в тиши, на оси, на печи, в грязи, в пыли, на цепи, в горсти, в дали, на груди, в тени, на мели* и иногда "на двер**и**" (хотя чаще нормативными отмечается вариант "на дв**е**ри").

Изначально в древнерусском местный падеж на "-у" был только у нескольких существительных мужского рода. Это было непродуктивное склонение: там были слова вроде "сын", "верх", "пол" и ещё несколько. Именно под влиянием форм вроде "на полу" некоторые другие существительные мужского рода и получили такую же вторую форму (древнерусская же была "в лѣсѣ"). Иными словами, образование этой формы — своего рода безотходное производство с попыткой деть куда-то существующую форму. :) Ведь в древнерусском было 5 типов склонения, и в процессе упрощения какие-то формы перераспределились.

- *Между прочим, родительный падеж множественного числа "стол**ов**" тоже из этого типа — исконно такого окончания не было почти нигде: в основном там было нулевое окончание (5 конь, 7 стол — для нас странно звучит, но так оно и было).*

Для остальных же, подавляющего большинства существительных, *предложный падеж = местный падеж*.