# Как правильно сказать: "на клею" либо "на клее"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Контекст такой: "Это изделие выполнено только на клею(е?) и шкантах, без каких-либо крепежей из металла".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В орфографическом словаре:
[клей](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?game=x&all=x&word=%EA%EB%E5%E9), кле́я и кле́ю, *предл.* в кле́е и в (на) клею́, *мн.* клеи́, -ёв.

В словаре русского словесного ударения:
**клей**, -я, о кле́е, в кле́е *и* в клею́, на клею́; *мн.* (в знач. сортов) клеи́, -ёв.

В толковом словаре Ожегова:
[КЛЕЙ](http://slovari.299.ru/word.php?id=12388&sl=oj), -я (-ю), о клее, **на клее** и **на клею, в клее** и **в клею**, м. Липкий затвердевающий состав для плотного соединения, скрепления частей чего-н. Канцелярский к. Столярный к. **Весь в клею** (испачкан клеем). **Обувь на клею.** || прил. клеевой, -ая, -ое. Клеевая краска (приготовленная на клею).

Особая форма предложного падежа — это так называемый местный падеж, используемый только с предлогами **в** и **на**. Подробные разъяснения есть [на нашем сайте](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35460/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/35465#35465).

Ваше предложение я бы написала так:
**Это изделие выполнено только** (на чём?) **на клею и шкантах, без каких-либо крепежей из металла.**